How to automatically schedule an interest rate every month in MySQL
I am using MySQL and I would like a field in my table to be periodically incremented per month. I'm  making a banking application and would like to give an interest rate for all the accounts... can anyone please advice me on how to get started or go about doing it?... thank you

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/event-scheduler.html
